# Дефолтные параметры в хранимых процедурах SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, хранимые-процедуры

Нужно создать процедуру, которая будет искать записи в таблице по параметру date, если дата не указана - ищем записи с текущей датой. Пытаюсь сделать вот так:

```
CREATE PROC getByDate (@date DATETIME = (SELECT GETDATE()))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    WHERE [date] = @date
END
```

Это синтаксически неверно, как передать дефолтное значение параметру правильно?

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД. А вообще просто `WHERE [date] = COALESCE(@date, NOW())`.

Comment: @Akina MS SQL, интересуют именно дефолтные параметры

Comment: @Legenras Сомневаюсь, что вы можете в дефолтные параметры засунуть динамическое содержимое. Скорее всего нужно будет написать = NULL и, например, проверять потом на этот NULL в теле процедуры. Это в любом практически языке делается подобным образом.

Comment: Дефолтный параметр должен быть литералом. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 *default — значение параметра по умолчанию. Если для некоторого параметра определено значение по умолчанию, то процедуру можно выполнить без указания значения этого параметра. Значение по умолчанию должно быть константой или может быть равно NULL. Значение константы может иметь вид шаблона, что позволяет использовать ключевое слово LIKE при передаче параметра в процедуру.*

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать следующий метод.

Значение по умолчанию - NULL.

**SQL**

```
CREATE PROC getByDate 
(
    @date DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE [date] = COALESCE(@date, GETDATE());
END
```